# What is the right input to complete this =ImportXML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to automate pulling number of review and rating from Trip Advisor... how would I find the right xpath query to pull? I have been trying to pull and have been getting errors or just the headers.

=IMPORTXML("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g57653-d15065834-Reviews-Hampton_Inn_Suites_Culpeper-Culpeper_Virginia.html","/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span","en_US")

I know the xpath is not the one represented above... if anyone knows what the best input would be to get "120 review" and "4.5/5", it'd be greatly appreciated!

=IMPORTXML("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g57653-d15065834-Reviews-Hampton_Inn_Suites_Culpeper-Culpeper_Virginia.html","/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span","en_US")

I know the xpath is not the one represented above... if anyone knows what the best input would be to get "120 review" and "4.5/5", it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

***Rating***: `=importxml(A1,"//*[@id='ABOUT_TAB']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]")&"/5"`

***Reviews***: `=join(,importxml(A1,"//*[@id='ABOUT_TAB']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/span[2]"))`

[image]

Comment: Was there anything else done to make this work other than switching the double quotations to single and correcting the span"[#]" at the end? Trying to do the same for another link and keep getting N/A.... I have tried the xpath and full xpath and still no luck.